# jQuery menu is displaying its childs on its left instead that on its right

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I have a simple page in which I have a jQuery menu with a few childs. The menu is aligned on the left of the page, contained in the second `td` of a `tr`. The menu is working, but it's displaying its kids on the left instead than the default setting right. I used a custom css for jQuery, to fit well in my page: I browsed it but couldn't find any right left option! I only found that it had different styles for left and right menus, so there must be an option to modify the direction, but I didn't find how to set that option. Can anyone help?

This is the website if my words weren't clear: http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Assets | Cicada3301's Website</title>
     <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/stylesheet.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/jquery-ui-stylesheet.css'>
  <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/scripts.js"></script>
    <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/me.jpg'>
    </head>
    <body>
            <ul id='menu'>
                <li><a href='#'>Images</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'><a href='me.jpg'>me.jpg</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'><a href='cheese.jpg'>cheese.jpg</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='#'>Stylesheets</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'><a href='stylesheet.css'>stylesheet.css</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'><a href='jquery-ui-stylesheet.css'>jquery-ui-stylesheet.css</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li><li><a href='#'>Scripts</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'><a href='scripts.js'>scripts.js</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'><a href='jquery-1.10.2.min.js'>jquery-1.10.2.min.js</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'><a href='jquery-ui.js'>jquery-ui</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li><li><a href='#'>Fonts</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'><a href='Computerfont.ttf'>Computerfont.ttf</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

`
And here is the css:

http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/jquery-ui-stylesheet.css
Sorry.. it was too long to put it in the body

Comment: The submenu is appearing on the right side of the menu for me from the link you gave. Is that what you mean? Also, could you please post the relevant code here so that we don't have to look through all of the code on your website, and also so that this question is self-contained?

Comment: That's strange... for me the menu is displaying the submenu on the left... sure, just lemme upload the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS**

Changed `width` to `14%` instead of `100%`.

```
 .ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
       width: 14%;
 }
```

Comment: Oh! Strange... i didn't even change that... let me try again